# Pandas: Merge Dataframes Based on Condition but Keep NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2, which I would like to merge on the column 'id' where the 'triggerdate' from df1 falls between the 'startdate' and 'enddate' of df2, however, keep the rows where there's no match.

df1:

```
id  triggerdate
a    09/01/2022
a    08/15/2022
b    06/25/2022
c    06/30/2022
c    07/01/2022
```

df2:

```
id startdate   enddate     value
a  08/30/2022  09/03/2022     30
b  07/10/2022  07/15/2022      5
c  06/28/2022  07/05/2022     10
```

Expected Output:

```
id triggerdate  startdate  enddate     value
a  09/01/2022  08/30/2022  09/03/2022     30
a  08/15/2022         NaN         NaN    NaN
b  06/25/2022         NaN         NaN    NaN
c  06/30/2022  06/28/2022  07/05/2022     10
c  07/01/2022  06/28/2022  07/05/2022     10
```

The approach that I have taken so far is:

```
df_merged = df1.merge(df2, on = ['id'], how='outer')

output = df_merged.loc[
             df_merged['triggerdate'].between(
                 df_merged['startdate'], 
                 df_merged['enddate'], inclusive='both')]
```

However, this approach does the following 1) Matches the 'id' values in df1 with df2 regardless of whether the condition is met and 2) then drops all the rows where the condition isn't met.

Unfortunately, I had no luck finding the solution online.

What would be the recommended approach to get the expected output?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Instead of `how='outer'` try `how='left'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2['startdate'],df2['enddate'])
df['value'] = pd.Series(df2['value'].tolist(),index = idx).reindex(df['triggerdate']).tolist()
```

Old answer:

Try `pd.merge_asof()`

modify df2 to merge on date column

```
df2 = (pd.concat([df2,
df2[['id','enddate']]
.rename({'enddate':'startdate'},axis=1)]))
```

Then merge

```
(pd.merge_asof(df.reset_index().sort_values('triggerdate'),
df2.sort_values('startdate'),
left_on = 'triggerdate',
right_on = 'startdate',
by = 'id')
.sort_values('index')
.drop('index',axis=1))
```

Output:

```
  id triggerdate  startdate    enddate  value
4  a  2022-09-01 2022-08-30 2022-09-03   30.0
3  a  2022-08-15        NaT        NaT    NaN
0  b  2022-06-25        NaT        NaT    NaN
1  c  2022-06-30 2022-06-28 2022-07-05   10.0
2  c  2022-07-01 2022-06-28 2022-07-05   10.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, rhug123! I did some random spot checks and everything looks good!

Your approach doesn't seem to factor in the end dates. Just out of curiosity, why wouldn't this be necessary? I apologize if I am misunderstanding this.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to include that functionality but it worked for the example so I didn't realize. I have made an edit that should work better.

Comment: Absolutely no problem! I truly appreciate your help with this! 

Going through your updated approach and trying to understand how and why this works. In your first step, you've created new rows and reassigned the end dates as their new start dates. But I haven't quite figured out how the final step uses this modification and solves everything.

I'll eventually figure it out. :) Thanks again!